# data frame transformation in r from Import

Tags: r, dataframe, transform

I importing data with multiple headers and would like to customize them as follows:

How to transform this data fram:

```
     X    X.1      X.2         X.3            X.4      G     G.1    G.2
1   NA   <NA>     <NA>        <NA>           <NA>      m       w     oA
2   NA   <NA>     <NA>        <NA>           <NA>   u15J 15bu18J    15J
3   NA   <NA>     <NA>        <NA>           <NA>    Ube      HU    Ube
4   NA   <NA>     <NA>        <NA>           <NA> Anzahl  Anzahl Anzahl
5 2015 Januar Kraftrad  UmitPerson      innerorts      1       2      3
6 2015 Januar Kraftrad  UmitPerson auf Autobahnen      -       -      -
7 2015 Januar Kraftrad SUberMittel      innerorts      1       2      3
```

to this dataframe:

```
     X    X.1      X.2         X.3            X.4 x.5     x.6 x.7 x.8
5 2015 Januar Kraftrad  UmitPerson      innerorts   m    u15J Ube   1
6 2015 Januar Kraftrad  UmitPerson auf Autobahnen   m    u15J Ube   -
7 2015 Januar Kraftrad SUberMittel      innerorts   m    u15J Ube   1
5 2015 Januar Kraftrad  UmitPerson      innerorts   w 15bu18J  HU   2
6 2015 Januar Kraftrad  UmitPerson auf Autobahnen   w 15bu18J  HU   -
7 2015 Januar Kraftrad SUberMittel      innerorts   w 15bu18J  HU   2
5 2015 Januar Kraftrad  UmitPerson      innerorts  oA     15J Ube   3
6 2015 Januar Kraftrad  UmitPerson auf Autobahnen  oA     15J Ube   -
7 2015 Januar Kraftrad SUberMittel      innerorts  oA     15J Ube   3
```

Data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
X = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,2015,2015,2015),
X.1 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,'Januar','Januar','Januar'),
X.2 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,'Kraftrad','Kraftrad','Kraftrad'),
X.3 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,'UmitPerson','UmitPerson','SUberMittel'),
X.4 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,'innerorts','auf Autobahnen','innerorts'),
G = c('m','u15J','Ube','Anzahl',1,'-',1),
G.1 = c('w','15bu18J','HU','Anzahl','2','-','2'),
G.2 = c('oA','15J','Ube','Anzahl','3','-','3'))
```

Comment: If you can explain how the G columns are supposed to match up with the x columns, there's probably an answer that will involve 1) break up the data frame into two and 2) joining the two appropriately.

Comment: I would like to have the rows 1,2,3 as column.